# Can you add rice flour to pastries to make them flakier?

Tags: baking, dough, pastry, gluten-free

The goal with many pastries seems to be limiting gluten development, by reducing the amount of water (e.g. replacing water with vodka in pie doughs) or reducing the time that the dough is handled to slow gluten development.

Given that rice flour has 0 gluten can I just substitute a quantity of all purpose for rice flour? what percentage should I swap out to achieve flaky pastries? Does rice flour have other effects on the finished product that I need to account for?

Comment: This can be a complicated substitution, depending on what you're making, the specific recipe, and your baking goals. Posting a specific recipe as an example might make it easier for folks to give advice. https://www.ehow.com/how_7773013_replace-wheat-flour-rice-flour.html

Comment: @AMtwo Sure, I don’t have a specific recipe in mind though— I was thinking like croissants or pie crust maybe?

Comment: Croissants and pie crust rely on a specific gluten structure (layers, separated by fat, rather than a lack of gluten development), fat, and steam (during baking) to create flakiness.

Comment: Okay, then shortcrust pastry or scones-- I'm not trying to eliminate all gluten formation, just speculating that rice flour might be able to be used to limit its development where you don't want it.